# Creating Custom Drupal 7 Registration Form

Tags: theming

I am trying to create a custom registration form on D7.
According to this [article](https://www.drupal.org/node/1779256)

The steps should be (theme name is icompany)

1. Modify `template.php` to override the registration form

   ```
   function icompany_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path){
     $hooks = array();
     // Make user-register.tpl.php available
     $hooks['user_register_form'] = array (
       'render element' => 'form',
       'path' => drupal_get_path('theme','icompany'),
       'template' => 'user-register',
       'preprocess functions' => array('icompany_preprocess_user_register_form'),
     );
     return $hooks;
   }
   ```
2. Create a second function which builds the form

   ```
   function icompany_preprocess_user_register_form(&$vars) {
     $args = func_get_args();
     array_shift($args);
     $form_state['build_info']['args'] = $args; 
     $vars['form'] = drupal_build_form('user_register_form', $form_state['build_info']['args']);    
   }
   ```
3. Create `user-register.tpl.php` with the newly styled form

My problem is this does not work.  My custom form does not seem to be called.

The alternative approach is to create page--user--register.tpl.php.  This sort of works, any text I put on the page appears but the form fields do not using the syntax

```
<?php
print render($form['account']['name']);
print render($form['account']['mail']);

?>
```

Comment: Have you  tried flushing your cache using the first approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the code and it's almost working as it's intended to be. One thing to note is when you placed the template file inside of the templates folder then the following should work.

On the **icompany_theme()** function, change the *path* value from `'path' => drupal_get_path('theme','icompany'),` to `'path' => drupal_get_path('theme','icompany') . '/templates',` which specifies to look for the file inside the templates folder.

Then flush your caches.

Comment: Thank you this was indeed the case. The only other thing I needed to add was 
<?php
  print drupal_render($form['actions']);

?>

Comment: That's great to hear! You're welcome!